# What is the difference between scale vs cataphyll?

Tags: botany, terminology

What is the difference between **scale** and **cataphyll** in botany - aren't these the same type of organ? 
E.g. do cycad cones have scales or cataphylls? Pine cones have scales, I understand the compound nature of pine cones - does that make them scales? 
On fern petioles/stipes there are often scale-like organs I've seen called scales (though they are not very scale-like).

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! What research have you done before asking it here?

Answer (score 1):

According to "[Plant Identification Terminology: An Illustrated Glossary](http://lib.du.ac.ir/documents/10157/60743/Plant+Identification+Terminology+Glossary.pdf)" (Harris & Harris, 2001):

**Scale**:

> Any thin, flat, scarious structure

- Note: "Scarious" = Thin, dry, and membranous in texture; not green

**Cataphyll**:

> Brown or colorless scale-like structures believed to be modified leaves

So "scale" is going to be used more broadly, while a "cataphyll" (though scale-like) is more specifically always some type of *modified leaf*.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cataphyll):

> Cataphylls include [bracts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bract), [bracteoles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracteole), and [bud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bud) scales, as well as any small leaves that resemble scales, which are known as scale leaves.

You can find good illustrations of cataphyll examples [here](http://dept.ca.uky.edu/PLS220/Stemcataphyll.pdf).

Comment: Thanks, I understand cataphylls a bit better. With scales, how does this definition fit in with scales on conifer cones? And do cycad cones have scales or are they just called sporophylls? I see in "Pterophytes and Gymnosperms" (Kramer and Green, 1990) they say cycads have 'scale-like sporophylls'. Why are they scale-like and not just scales?